# Unmappable character

Tags: encoding

```
  public class MyFirstApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(“I Rule!”);
    System.out.println(“The World”);
   }
  }
```

When try to compile It in cmd using `javac MyFirstApp.java` it says that `there is an unmappable character (0x9D) for encoding`. What Is the problem?

Comment: encoding in windows-1252

Comment: Shouldn't be any real "encoding". Except for embedded strings (but NOT the " around the strings), most ordinary languages (as opposed to the esoteric stuff over in Code Golf) use 7-bit ASCII for just about everything.

Answer (score 1):

The quotation marks in:

```
System.out.println(“I Rule!”);
System.out.println(“The World”);
```

are not correct. They are different for left & right. They should be plain ordinary "

```
System.out.println("I Rule!");
System.out.println("The World");
```

This type of problem is often caused by using a word processor (e.g., Word) rather than a text editor or "programmer's editor" (simplest typical example is Notepad, but there are plenty of free and low-cost alternatives that are much more powerful).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I actually used notepad++, do you know a way to change this?

Comment: If you can find any settings for Smart Quotes turn them off.